# What does asterisk inside square bracket of array declaration mean in C

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

I am writing a custom C99 parser. I got the grammar from [this](http://slebok.github.io/zoo/c/c99/iso-9899-tc3/extracted/index.html#direct-declarator) link. This grammar says following is a valid syntax for declaring arrays -

```
int arr[*];
```

Relevant part of the grammar is follwing -

```
direct-declarator ::=
    identifier
    "(" declarator ")"
    direct-declarator "[" type-qualifier-list? assignment-expression? "]"
    direct-declarator "[" "static" type-qualifier-list? assignment-expression "]"
    direct-declarator "[" type-qualifier-list "static" assignment-expression "]"
    direct-declarator "[" type-qualifier-list? "*" "]"
    direct-declarator "(" parameter-type-list ")"
    direct-declarator "(" identifier-list? ")"
```

I tried compiling a code with this declaration using gcc. It gave me following warning -

> error: ‘[*]’ not allowed in other than function prototype scope

So I tried declaring a function prototype with this type of syntax and it compiled without any error or warning. What I am not getting is what can this syntax possibly mean semantically. Any expert with an explanation?

Comment: It is just an explicit way to express that no value is being passed for that array dimension. (you must always provide the last, but preceding dimensions are optional) (that's the link I was looking for)

Comment: maybe read the rest of the standard, if you're going to write a parser?

Answer (score 4):

It's a declarator for a variable length array with unspecified size. Furhtermore, the following declaration

```
void func(size_t n, char s[n]);
```

is equivalent to simply writing:

```
void func(size_t n, char s[*]);
```

The above is particularly useful for writing headers, where you'd normally declare only the parameter types

```
void func(size_t, char [*]);
```